# Can't edit data in certain columns in attribute table

Tags: qgis-3, attribute-table, editing

I am able to edit certain attributes in my table, but not others. For any given record, I can edit all but two of the columns. Those two columns cannot be edited in any record. The non-editable records happen to be integer, though there are integer fields that I can edit.

Here's the schema
[image]

I'm editing by clicking the "Toggle Edit" button, then clicking in a field in a specific record. I can enter data for all except the circles fields.

The dbf file has not been opened/edited in anything other than QGIS

How do I enable those columns for editing? 
The source data is an ESRI shapefile, if that matters. I've closed the project and reloaded it and the problem remains the same.

QGIS 3.4.2, Windows 64 bit.

Comment: Do you mean you cannot edit data in the column or you cannot edit the schema of the column? I presume data. This question is unclear and lacks sufficient detail for me to help.

Comment: Which column names are you trying to edit?

Comment: I'd like to help, but you're not providing enough info.  What is an "ints"?  What QGIS version?  What exact steps are you taking in your edit process?  Has the shapefile's .dbf file ever been opened in a program other than QGIS or Arc? Screenshots of table schema and table view would really help.

Comment: All the fields with numeric initial characters have invalid field names. That's bound to cause parsing issues.

Comment: While I somehow manage to remember the 10 char limit, I can't seem to hold on to no numerics as first char. But that turns out not to be the issue (or at least not completely). My project has multiple layers, all of which are duplicates on the first, and thus all have the same underlying shapefile. On a whim I opened the shapefile in a new, blank map. In that project I can edit the data in any field.

Comment: @Llaves I had the same problem and went trough this question. This comment above solved it for me too. It may be a nice idea to post it as an answer to your question and self-approve it. It would help others to finde a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than closing and reloading the project, create a new project and add the troublesome layer to the new project. This worked for me and for @Vince, as noted in the comments.

Comment: If it work in a new project the problem is in the original project. So you may want to go to the layer properties choose the Attributes Form tab and check that the problematic field are set as editable